# Prove that none of the isomorphisms above can be extended to an isomorphism of the ring $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Q}^\times$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero rational numbers. If $\alpha=p/q\in G$, where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime integers, let $\phi: G \to G$ be the map which integer changes the primes 2 and 3 in the prime power factorizations of $p$ and $q$ (so, for example, $\phi(2^4 3^{11} 5^1 13^2) =3^4 2^{11} 5^1 13^2$, $\phi(3/16)=\phi(3/2^4)=2/3^4=2/81$, and $\phi$ is the identity on all rational numbers with numerators and denominators relatively prime to 2 and to 3).

a) Prove that $\phi$ is a group isomorphism.

b) Prove that there are infinitely many isomorphisms of the group $G$ to itself.

c) Prove that none of the isomorphisms above can be extended to an isomorphism of the ring $\mathbb{Q}$ to itself.

I have proven part (a) and (b). And I found that we can generalize $\phi$ by $\phi(p^m q^n ab)=p^n q ^m ab$, where $p,q$ are any primes.

How do I go about proving (c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that under a ring automorphism $\varphi,$  $\varphi(1) = 1.$ So, $\varphi(1+1) = \varphi(1) + \varphi(1) = 2 \neq 3.$

Comment: True. But how does this help me show that it doesn't extended to an isomorphism of the ring?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Your map sends 2 to 3, right?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: @UsernameUnknown And yet it cannot...

Comment: So it's not well-defined?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown It is not defined, period. What the answer shows is that any ring homomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the identity on $\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: So then how does this imply that the identity map is the only ring isomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown Indeed it does.